How to restart SSH daemon/service on Synology NAS with DSM 7.2?
How to restart SSH daemon/service on Synology NAS with DSM 7.2?
I already tried too many commands to remember them all, for example:
# synoservicectl --restart sshd

But none worked. Can anyone tell me what command to use on the latest to date version of DSM (7.2)?
Thank you.

I found out one command working, being rooted with sudo -i:
# synosystemctl restart sshd.service
[sshd.service] restarted.

Of course, it likely is possible to run it with sudo, but I did not test it.
Hope it helps!
